# Spring ругается на некорректную ссылку в xml файле

Tags: java, spring

Начал изучат спринг, читаю Spring 4 для профессионалов. Приведённый в той книге пример не корректен. Там приводится конфигурационный xml файл такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="provider"
      class="HelloWorldMessageProvider"/>
<bean id="render"
      class="StandartOutMessageRender"
      p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/>
</beans>
```

IDE ругается на:`xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`, а при попытке перехода по этой ссылке выскакивает 404. Что делать?

Comment: а сама программа работает? Бины появляются?

Comment: Я заменил эту ссылку на другую (одну из тех, что появляются при нажатии `ctrl+space`(http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema)), и теперь всё работает.